# Guice module integration issue with REST

Tags: rest, guice

**Guice module integration issue with REST** 
I have define one AOP guice based module, but when I tried to integrate with  REST code, methodInvocation.proceed retun null.
What might be best way to solve this issue.

```
Define AOP Guice based module as below 

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface NotOnWeekends {}
public class WeekendBlocker implements MethodInterceptor {

  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {

    Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();

    if (today.getDisplayName(DAY_OF_WEEK, LONG, ENGLISH).startsWith("S")) {

      throw new IllegalStateException(

          invocation.getMethod().getName() + " not allowed on weekends!");
    }

    return invocation.proceed();

  }

}

public class NotOnWeekendsModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {

    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(NotOnWeekends.class), 

        new WeekendBlocker());
  }
}

But I tried to Integrate this with my REST API 


    public class WorkerBean implements Worker {

    @Autowired
    private WorkerRepository workerRepository;

    @Override
    @NotOnWeekends
    public Collection<Worker> findAll() {

        Collection<Worker> workers = workerRepository.findAll();

        return workers;
    }


@RestController
public class WorkerController {


    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/api/workers",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Worker>> getWorkers() {


        Worker worker = Guice.createInjector(new NotOnWeekendsModule()).getInstance(Worker.class);

        Collection<Worker> worker = worker.findAll(); // return null 

        ....
    }
```

Comment: `findAll()` returns null or `worker` is null?